# Как вставить пробел в значение некоторых option в select?

Tags: html

Нужно вставить пробел или отступ в значения option. Но когда вставляю то он удаляется или не реагирует. Пробовал `&nbsp;` но не помогает.

```
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>    1.2</option>
            <option>    1.3</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>    2.1</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: &nbsp; попробуйте

Comment: &nbsp перед значением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как Вы, интересно, пробовали? Всё помогает:

```html
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;1.2</option>
   <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;1.3</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;2.1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Всё работает. Видимо как то неправильно в переменной было значение, когда вставил напрямую этот текст то всё заработало. Сейчас не могу понять почему не работало.